# Lucene query for Todays date

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack

I'm trying to filter my Elastic Search data based on a date field to show me everything for todays date.

In Kibana I can use the KQL query using `now/d` but I need the equivalent for Lucene, any help? I would've thought it'd be the same but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: The `kql` tag stands for Kusto Query Language

Answer (score 1):

`field:[now/d TO now/d]` seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported yet at the Lucene level and is still [work in progress](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6302)

Comment: work in progress for 7 years! dont think it's gonna happen anytime soon

Comment: Migrated to Github [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene/issues/7363), you can freely chime in to enquire where that stands.